# Cumulative percentage calculation in a group by dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

A grouped-by dataset:

```
Col-a   col-b   
24567a   2
         3
         4
         6
56789c   1
         2
         3
```

Is an existing group-by dataframe. Could anyone please tell me how do i get an output in the below format:

```
Col-a   col-b   Cum-Percentage
24567a   2       25%
         3       50%
         4       75%
         6       100%
56789b   1       33.33%
         2       66.66%
         3       100%
```

Where the each instance is expressed as a fraction of total instance occurring in a group-by dataframe (Pandas, python 3.8).Table shown in the below image if it's unclear above.  Any help would be wonderful, Thanks in advance! :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ6II.png)

Comment: create a column for cumcount in grouped object and get percentage of col-b in cum_count column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Col-a is the index: use [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) + [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map) to apply formatting:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col-a': ['24567a', '24567a', '24567a', '24567a', '56789c', '56789c',
              '56789c'],
    'col-b': [2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3]
}).set_index('Col-a')

g = df.groupby(level=0)
df['cum-percent'] = (
        (g.cumcount() + 1) / g['col-b'].transform('count') * 100
).map('{:.2f}%'.format)
```

```
        col-b cum-percent
Col-a                    
24567a      2      25.00%
24567a      3      50.00%
24567a      4      75.00%
24567a      6     100.00%
56789c      1      33.33%
56789c      2      66.67%
56789c      3     100.00%
```

---

If Col-a is a column with spaces instead of values use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) + [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html#pandas-series-ffill) then use the `groupby` functions as above:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col-a': ['24567a', '', '', '', '56789c', '', ''],
    'col-b': [2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3]
})

df['Col-a'] = df['Col-a'].replace({'': np.nan}).ffill()
g = df.groupby('Col-a')
df['cum-percent'] = (
        (g.cumcount() + 1) / g['col-b'].transform('count') * 100
).map('{:.2f}%'.format)
```

```
    Col-a  col-b cum-percent
0  24567a      2      25.00%
1  24567a      3      50.00%
2  24567a      4      75.00%
3  24567a      6     100.00%
4  56789c      1      33.33%
5  56789c      2      66.67%
6  56789c      3     100.00%
```